# Total Probability and Events Negation

Tags: probability

I would like to ask if I have an event when flipping a coin for $n$ times until a **first** head is observed.

Event $E$:  the first head on even numbered flip

Event $H$:  head on first flip

Let $P(H) = p$

I am required to find $P(E)$

I know $P(E) = P(E|H)P(H) + P(E|H^c)P(H^c)$ where $H^c$ be the negation or complement of $H$; and $P(E|H)=0, P(H) = p, P(H^c)=1-p$.

But I am stuck at $P(E|H^c)$. The solution stated that $P(E|H^c)=P(E^c)=1-P(E)$
but I do not understand. What is the negation or complement of $E$, let's denote is as $E^c$, in plain English? My assumption of $E^c$ is that it refers to first head on odd numbered flip.

However I don't see why the probability of having a first head on even-flipped while having a tail on first flip equals to the probability of having the first head on odd numbered flip.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

> However I don't see why the probability of having a first head on
>   even-flipped while having a tail on first flip equals to the
>   probability of having the first head on odd numbered flip.

It is just a matter of counting your flips. Imagine you are starting over after the first flip is known to be tails. You don't care what was the outcome, you just put your counter to 1 again, flip and the odd-flipped head probability is $p_o$. If you don't reset your count, the only thing changed is the fact that you start over from 2, so all even counts become odd and vice versa, so same probability.

You can think of it as sticking a tails result to the beginning of your result queue. Since it has probability = 1, there is no change in math, but numbering is shifted, that's all.